# Split a column by regex and keep only matches in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I need to have a column per my regex match.

Consider below dataframe:

```
Letter      Actions
r1          a95,a20
r2          a30,a12-rf,a15,a75
r3          0
r4          a15,a74
r5          a11
```

I expect:

```
Letter      Action1      Action2      Action3      Action4
r1          a95          a20          
r2          a30          a12          a15          a75
r3          
r4          a15          a74
r5          a11
```

I have below but it keeps every thing else as well while I just need the pattern matches:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['r1', 'a95,a20'],
     ['r2', 'a30,a12-rf,a15,a75'],
     ['r3', '0'],
     ['r4', 'a15,a74'],
     ['r5', 'a11']],
    columns=['Letter', 'Actions'])

Actions = df['Actions'].str.split(r'([a]\d{2})', expand=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `str.extractall()`

```
(df.set_index('Letter')['Actions']
.str.extractall(r'([a]\d{2})')[0]
.unstack()
.rename(lambda x: 'Action{}'.format(x+1),axis=1)
.reset_index()
.rename_axis(None,axis=1))
```

Another possibility is using `str.split()`

```
df.set_index('Letter')['Actions'].str.split(r'(?:\D+)?,',expand=True)
```

Output:

```
  Letter Action1 Action2 Action3 Action4
0     r1     a95     a20     NaN     NaN
1     r2     a30     a12     a15     a75
2     r4     a15     a74     NaN     NaN
3     r5     a11     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You've used `split` wrong. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html

Something like this is probably what you want to do, although you will still keep the `-rf` parts:

```
split(',', expand=True)

     0       1     2     3
0  a95     a20  None  None
1  a30  a12-rf   a15   a75
2    0    None  None  None
3  a15     a74  None  None
4  a11    None  None  None
```

Also, your regex is hitting some common beginner problems so it would be a good idea to read up on regex in python. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html. In particular your `[a]` is quite meaningless since it is the same as a plain `a`.

If you know the maximum number of elements you can split to, then you can use a regex and `extract` which also does what you want. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html

Something like

```
extract(r'(a\d\d)(?:-[^,]+)?(?:,(a\d\d)(?:-[^,]+)?)?(?:,(a\d\d)(?:-[^,]+)?)?(?:,(a\d\d)(?:-[^,]+)?)?')

     0    1    2    3
0  a95  a20  NaN  NaN
1  a30  a12  a15  a75
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  a15  a74  NaN  NaN
4  a11  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

In terms of matching something like `a12-rf` and only keeping the `a12` part, you need a regex like `(a\d\d)(?:-[^,]+)?` to capture `a12` with `(a\d\d)`, and then match but not keep `-rf` you use the non-capture group `?:` modifier, and then match `-rf` with `-[^,]+` where `[^,]+` matches 1-or-more non-`,` characters.

This is how I got `(a\d\d)(?:-[^,]+)?`. For the other parts elements in your string, you can wrap this pattern in its own non-capture group to handle the being optional and adding a comma to match. `(?:,<prev_pattern>)?`. And then you copy-paste that `,<pattern>` match as many times as you need.

If you do not know how many of these elements you could hit, then you can use `extractall` and then pivot the `MultiIndex` it uses. This sounds complicated (and I have to admit that doing it in my head is a bit painful) but is quite simple in practice.

```
extractall(r'(a\d\d)(?:-[^,]+)?').unstack()[0]

match    0    1    2    3
0      a95  a20  NaN  NaN
1      a30  a12  a15  a75
3      a15  a74  NaN  NaN
4      a11  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: my regex is not that complex, it is a set of specific letters following specific set of numbers, and I got what I have wanted but with extra data. [rhug123's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76502902/7794309) solved exactly what I needed.